# why do my web pages render raw html before applying CSS styles - both locally via Visual Studio Code & Firefox as well hosted on github?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, visual-studio-code

I have web pages that render raw html before appliying CSS Styles - this is really ugly

The GitHub link is here: https://fishbite.github.io/draw/index.html

and the repository link is here: [fishbite.github.io/draw repository](https://github.com/Fishbite/draw)

The Stylesheets are loaded on the head section of the pages and JavaScript loaded before the closing body tag.

The problem happens when running locally via Visual Studio Code with Live Server extension and Firefox and also when hosted on GitHub.

I have looked up similar if not exact replicants of this problem (a FOUC (a flash of unstyled content)) and the solutions offered appear to be what I am already doing: loading stylesheets in the head and JS before the closing body tag.

I initially had an

```html
onload="func()"
```

parameter in the opening body tag which called a function. However, removing this did not help or fix the problem.

The is my first serious attempt to upload a complete site to GitHub and I initially thought the problem was occuring locally due to the development environment described above, so I was very disappointed to realise that was not the case.

```js
/*
****** main JavaScript for first menu button ******
****** code for the other buttons is not important ******
*/

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/* Function to draw a square inside
a canvas with border around the square
*/
function square(a) {  
// Set canvas size + a border width!
ctx.canvas.width = a * 1.1;
ctx.canvas.height = a * 1.1;
  
// Set line start point
let x = (ctx.canvas.width / 2) - (a / 2);
let y = (ctx.canvas.height / 2) - (a / 2);

// Draw first line of square setting line colour
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgrey';
ctx.moveTo(x + 0, y + 0);
ctx.lineTo(x + 0, y + a);
// Draw second, third & fourth line of square
ctx.lineTo(x + a, y + a);
ctx.lineTo(x + a, y + 0);
ctx.lineTo(x + 0, y + 0);
// Draw an outline around the shape
ctx.stroke();
}

let a = "";
let b = "";

// callSquare() passes the value of the input box to square()
function callSquare() {
  let b = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
 // parseFloat converts the input string to a float
 a = parseFloat(b);  
  document.getElementById('outputOne').innerHTML = "You typed: " + a;
  if (a === 1) {
  document.getElementById('outputTwo').innerHTML = "This is a square of " + a + " unit. Look closely! O.^.O";
    square(a);
 }
  else if (a === 0) {    document.getElementById('outputTwo').innerHTML = "A square of " + a + " units is technically not a square!";
     square(a);
  }
  else if (a < 0) {    document.getElementById('outputTwo').innerHTML = "Doh! That's a negative number. Not allowed!";
  }
  else if (a > 225) {    document.getElementById('outputTwo').innerHTML = "Boom Shackalack! Number too high! 225 is the limit";
  }
  else if (a !== 1) {  
  document.getElementById('outputTwo').innerHTML = "This is a square of " + a + " units";
    square(a);
 }
  
}
```

```css
/* 
****** styles.css ******
*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share+Tech+Mono&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(34, 33, 32);
  background-image: url("https://fishbite.github.io/draw/images/darknoise.png");
  background-size: 25px;
  background-attachment: fixed; /* fixes the background in place */
  
  font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fc6500;
}
#canvas {
  background: darkgreen;
}

#intro {
  margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  max-width: 550px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#cell-1 {
  text-align: justify;
}

#input-div {
  text-align: center;
}

#inputBox {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#cell-2 {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 150px;
}

/* 
****** menu.css *******
*/
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: -10em;
    top: 25%;
    width: 8em;
    background: rgba(49, 49, 49, 1);    
    margin: -3em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0.5em 1.0em 0.5em 2.5em;
    border-radius: .0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px outset rgb(27, 27, 27);
    border-left: 0;
  }

  #menu li{
    list-style: none;    
  }

  #menu-container {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container*/
    flex-direction: column; /* make main axis vertical*/
    justify-content: center; /* center items vertically - in flex-column*/
    align-items: center; /* center items horizontally - in flex column*/
  }

  #menu li a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* make main axis horizontal*/
    height: 50px;
    
    text-decoration: none;    
    align-items: center; /* center items vertically - in flex row*/
    justify-content: center; /* center items horizontally - in flex row*/
    text-align: center; /* center anything misbehaving - top & bot row of list*/
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, 
    rgb(27, 27, 27) 2px,  
    rgba(49, 49, 49, 1) 2px, 
    rgba(49, 49, 49, 1) 94%, 
    rgb(184, 238, 248));
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(77, 77, 77);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(30, 30, 30);

    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  /* for accessibility with no mouse or touch screen*/
  #menu a {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
  }

  #menu a:focus {
/* move the <a> element out to the right*/
    right: -8em;
    background: rgb(30, 34, 43);
  }

  #menu a { transition: 0.2s }

  #menu:hover a:focus { 
 /*ensures <a> element stays put when menu has focus with mouse*/
    left: 0;
    background: none;
  }
/* back to using a mouse or touch screen!*/
  #menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 241, 46);
    border-bottom: inset 2px solid rgb(2, 3, 3);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(32, 32, 32);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgb(27, 27, 27);
  }

  #menu:hover {
    left: 0;
  }
  #menu {transition: 0.2s;
  }
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
 
    <body>
      <div id="menu-container">
        <ul id=menu>
          <h2>menu</h2>
          <li><a href="index.html">Interactive Square</a>
            <li><a href="fill-rect.html">Fill Rect</a>
            <li><a href="fill-clear-stroke.html">Fill/Clear/Stroke Rect</a>
            <li><a href="stroke-triangle.html">Stroke Triangle</a>
            <li><a href="stroke-circle-triangle.html">Stroke Circle Triangle</a>
         </ul>
        </div>

      <h1>JS App to Draw a Square</h1>
      <div id="intro">
      <p>Use of a canvas and JavaScript drawing elements:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Take a user input value from an input element type of 'number'</li>
        <li>Set the canvas size to the input value + 10%</li>
        <li>Draw a square equal in dimension to the input value</li>
        <li>Inject text into html &lt;p&gt; elements based on user input value</li>
      </ul></div>
     <div id="container">
       <div id="cell-1">
         <p>Type a <b>non-negative</b> number in the box to draw a square, or alternatively use the scrolly arrows.</p>
        <div id="input-div">
         <input type="number" id="inputBox" oninput="callSquare()">
        
<p id="outputOne">You haven't entered a number.</p>
          </div>
       </div>
      <div id="cell-2">
  <p id="outputTwo">Your square will be below.</p>
        <div id="canvas-div">
      <canvas width="0" height="0" id='canvas'></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I expected the above html to load the stylesheets and apply the styles before rendering the pages.

Instead, it renders the raw html and then applies the styles in a visually jerky fashion

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! On the last snippent, you seem to be missing your CSS files, so it's not loading at all. If you included the link to the website that this issue is occurring on, that would help a lot too.

Comment: Thank you for your welcome Jack, your feedback is most welcome. I added a link to the github site and repository. I've also posted the CSS as you suggested was missing and the main JavaScript used on the first menu button. The JavaScript for the other buttons is not important, other than to know they are loaded using the onload="func()" in the opening body tag.

Comment: Both pages (the snippet in the question and the Github) loaded as they should for me. There was no delay in the loading CC loading.

Comment: Your doctype is malformed. Fix that.

Comment: Thank you Alohci, that fixed my problem. I will post the answer. Thank you Jack for the contribution. I'm not sure why it worked for you but I had an error in the doctype declaration where I put the ! mark after DOCTYPE! instead of before hand: !DOCTYPE. Thanks again.

Comment: Gald your issue is resolved, it may have been my browser or a number of other reasons why it worked for me and not for you.

Comment: Every which way but loose. All contributions have been welcome and gladly accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pointed out to me that I had made an error in my doctype declaration. I had written

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
```

instead of

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Correcting that fixed the problem of the html being rendered before the css styles were applied.

Thank you Alohci!

Answer (score 0):

The code probably can not find stylesheets at the given path or there is an error in these files.

Comment: Hi Sajjad, thanks for the contribution. The strange thing is that the styles do get applied - eventually - here's the link: [link](https://fishbite.github.io/draw/index.html) if you want to see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

In case someone had the same problem, it is also caused if you don't place your scripts in the head of the html